# Mongoid Single TAble Inheritance _type field not fetched when it is used in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Two Mongoid document models, one inherits from the other. (1) When the parent model is queried for its "_type" field for the parent's type, the returned records come back correctly matching the type, however, these records have NO _type field.

(2) So if the parent model is queried again only this time without the _type field constraint, the returned records will contain both the parent and the child models as expected, and these records DO have _type field.

(3) if now we repeat (1), those records WILL have the _type field. Are you experiencing this oddity as well?

Example:

```
# parent class
class Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
end

# child class
class Estimate < Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
end

rails c
# (1)
Invoice.where(_type: "Invoice").to_a.map(&:_type)
# NoMethodError: undefined method `_type' for #<Invoice:0x007ffeada82178>

# (2)
Invoice.all.to_a.map(&:_type)
# => ["Estimate", "Invoice", "Invoice"]

# (3)
Invoice.where(_type: "Invoice").to_a.map(&:_type)
# => ["Invoice", "Invoice"]


reload!

(1)
Invoice.where(_type: "Invoice").to_a.map(&:_type)
# NoMethodError: undefined method `_type' for #<Invoice:0x007ffeada82178>
```

MONGOID VERSION: 5.0.2

Comment: Which version of Mongoid? I am not able to reproduce this on 5.1.4

Comment: Ahh, excuse me, please see edit, but it's 5.0.2